# Как сделать массив с изменяемым размером?

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Как изменить размер динамического массива, если изначально у него один размер, а потом другой(больший)?

Comment: Что такое "динамический массив" в данном случае? Как он был создан изначально?

Comment: @AnT int * ass= new int[ size ];

Comment: Я бы рассмотрел в таком случае возможность использования std::vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер массива, созданного через `new[]` невозможно увеличить. Для таких массивов выход только один:

1. Создать аналогичный массив большего размера
2. Скопировать (переместить) в него данные из исходного массива
3. Уничтожить исходный массив.

Comment: Просто проблема в том, что массив по указателю передается в функцию. И в ней же изменяется его размер и значения.

Comment: @hurrypurp: В такой ситуации задача не имеет решения. Хочешь-не хочешь, а указатель на новый массив придется как-то передавать из функции наружу. Например, передавать в функцию не указатель на массив, а *ссылку* на указатель на массив.